# Passing JSON weird behaviour

Tags: html, typescript, web-component

I'm trying to pass some arguments into a web component, and it is giving a very weird behavior. Can anyone explain why? I am passing an object like

```
<my-fast-styled-comp  
                designToken={{"--font-bold":"700","--font-thin":"200","--color-primary":"teal","--color-accent":"yellow"}} ></my-fast-styled-comp>
```

And I'm trying to log the value of the design token simply, but if there is even a little space in the argument somewhere, it prints the output to that place only. (FYI, this component is inside a template literal, ie, it is called render (html`` `\`)).

And this is how I'm trying to console log it

```
@customElement({
  name: 'my-fast-styled-comp',
  template,
  styles,
})
export class MyFastStyledComp extends FASTElement {
  @attr designToken: any = {};

  designTokenChanged(oldValue: object[], newToken: object[]) {
    const data = this.designToken;
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

I tried changing ways to console log it, but that makes the problem worse sometimes, it doesn't even print it.

Comment: Just curious, does `designToken` have to be a JSON string? If you just use a string for the attribute for debugging purposes, does it work all the time? Looking at [the docs](https://www.fast.design/docs/fast-element/defining-elements#customizing-attributes), it looks like almost everything has to be a string, which you can customize with a custom converter, except for the built-in boolean converter

Comment: No not at all, but I thought this implementation would make the styling more flexible, just pass in a new JSON string and get a whole different element.

Answer (score 0):

Your not quoting your **attribute** `designToken`, which is totally valid, quotes are not required...

BUT, the HTML parser will stop processing the **value** at the first space.

You can replace all double-quotes in your JSON **string** with single-quotes

Then **add** double-quotes for the whole value